# Where can I find tutorials about graph theoretical regression

Tags: regression, graph-theory

Hi I am a biology graduate currently working on a problem that requires me to use Graph theoretical regression model. While I have taken a couple of applied regression model courses. I don't have much knowledge of theoretical statistics. I was wondering where can I find tutorials for applying a graph theoretic model or creating one for your particular problem. I would be glad if some one can point me to a resource which can enable me to use the model for my problem.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at this paper [here](http://lu.seas.harvard.edu/files/yuelu/files/graphrecon_isbi_reprocessed_1.pdf) 
I hope this paper can help  a little bit